# Дух и душа

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Со смысловой разницей понятий "дух" и "душа" у меня затруднений нет (да и не это предмет обсуждения). А вот интересна их лексическая разница. 
Вроде бы корень у них один. Но звучат несколько иначе. Это что, сделано, чтобы как-то различать понятия, или слова образовались независимо друг от друга? В других языках, насколько я знаю, эти слова даже не однокоренные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос на тему о душе, духовности и дыхании человека. Если человек живой, то он инстинктивно дышит, у него есть душа (сознание, интеллект), в которой обитает божий дух (интуиция).
Разные формы корня (душ-, дыш-, дох-, дух-, дых-) передают разные смыслы смежных, близких понятий. Как только дыхание прекращается, душа (легчайшая оболочка, *воздушный шарик*) вместе с духом человека покидает его тело. Что тут еще можно сказать.

Comment: дых, дух, вздох...эх, ох, ух, ах. пока дышишь и ощущаешь. нет--помер---душа в пятки--обморок.
последний вздох--и... нет тебя. Жена в постели иногда будит--дыхание задержал, боится.
учащенное дыхание--радость от работы и деятельности, впечатления. замкнутый цикл.
Вопросов нет. 
душа--задушить можно. тонкая такая штука,  ее можно, а дух сломать нельзя, если есть.

Answer (score 1):

*Боевой дух, чистая душа.

Присутствие духа, душа в пятки. (Хотя правильнее было бы "дух в пятки ушёл").

Собраться с духом, согревать душой.

Одухотворенный, воодушевленный.*

В чем вопрос-та?! )))